# Def function intro

Tags: python, function, syntax

I have to define a function named introduce(). It asks for the name of a person twice, and then introduce each of the two people to the other. The function introduce() takes one string parameter

for instance it would say:
What is your name?
John

And What is your name? Mike

it would then return:

John meet Mike,

Mike meet John

the code I have so far is

```
 def introduce(intro):
     1st = input('What is your name?: ')
     2nd = input('And what is your name? ')
     print(1st(input) 'meet' 2nd(input))
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong, I am new to Python so I am not too familiar with some of the elements in it

Comment: Very few (?) programming languages might have variable names starting in a digit.

Comment: I guess you should read at least a bit of a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html); this is pretty basic stuff. Read the error messages you're getting, they will point you in the right direction (for example that `1st` is not a legal variable name)...

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers thus far have said that you shouldn't be using `input`.  You should rather be using `raw_input`.

Comment: @devnull The asker didn't specify a version, but `print` is being used as a function, so this may well be Python 3, which doesn't have `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, variable names in Python (and most other languages) can't start with digits, so use `first` and `second`.

You're also doing some weird syntactical stuff in your `print` call, which definitely doesn't work. Once you assign the two variables, just print them out--there's no need to refer to the `input` function again. Just pass `first`, `second`, and anything else as comma-separated arguments to the `print` function:

```
print(first, 'meet', second)
```

I *highly* recommend you work through some of the [Python tutorials](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). This is all really basic syntactical stuff; doing the examples there will likely help you out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Python, variable names cannot start with numerals, so try naming them `first` and `second`

Second, the `(input)` after the variables is unnecessary (and wrong). The variable name speaks for itself.

Third, separate your variables and `'meet'` with a comma, so they're printed with a space between them and automatically joined together. There are other ways, but this is the simplest

```
def introduce(intro):
    first = input('What is your name?: ')
    second = input('And what is your name? ')
    print(first, 'meet', second)
    print(second, 'meet', first)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to not start variable names with numbers.

the input is saved in the variable *1st*. You don't need to use `1st(input)`. Instead, you just `print(first)

Also, there is a problem with the way you join the strings. It can be done in two ways:

```
#Method 1:
print(1st, 'meet' , '2nd')
```

or

```
#Method 2:
print(1st + ' meet ' + 2nd)
```

the difference is: a comma will add the space, whereas a space is required when using *+* (at least, they are the only differences you need to be aware of.)